# Imprimir un Reporte (ReportViewer) desde Codigo (Sin vista Previa)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//aqui muestro mi reporte en la pagina

 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString()))
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tabla where Cod_user='" + Session["Cod_user"] + "'", con);
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
DataTable t = new DataTable();
da.Fill(t);
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", t);           ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/Report1.rdlc"); 
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
}
}
}

//boton imprimir
protected void Imprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Tengo un reporte con reportviewer de una factura que me trae datos de la BD, quisiera poder imprimirlo sin necesidad de usar la vista previa es decir hacerlo desde programación con un botón aparte, osea no utilizar el que tiene el reportviewer por defecto.

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias

SOLUCION CON JQUEY

```html
<!--script para imprimir-->
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Print() {
  var report = document.getElementById("<%=ReportViewer1.ClientID%>");
 var div = report.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

 var reportContents;
 for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  if (div[i].id.indexOf("VisibleReportContent") !== -1) {
   reportContents = div[i].innerHTML;
   break;
  }
 }
 var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
 frame1.name = "frame1";
 frame1.style.position = "absolute";
 frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
 document.body.appendChild(frame1);
 var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document :frame1.contentDocument;
 frameDoc.document.open();
 frameDoc.document.write(reportContents);
 frameDoc.document.write("<style> @page { size: portrait; } .head { display: none; }></style>");
 frameDoc.document.close();
 setTimeout(function () {
  window.frames["frame1"].focus();
  window.frames["frame1"].print();
  document.body.removeChild(frame1);
 }, 500);   
 }
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta e es la solución que dan en [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734277/print-a-reportviewer-without-preview), y [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) la solución propuesta por microsoft.

Espero que sea de utilidad.

```
    //boton imprimir
    protected void Imprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

        //cargas el contendido del reporte.

        PrintDialog prt = new PrintDialog();
        rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = prt.PrinterSettings.PrinterName; 
        rd.PrintToPrinter(copies, true, 1, 1000); 
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no me funciona, paracere que es para windowform, y yo trabajo con webforms

Comment: @sunflower lo pudiste solucionar ?

Comment: @sunflower pudiste hacer en asp.net ?

Comment: hola si pude hacerlo necesitas ayuda? @Pierro

Comment: @sunflower puedes poner el codigo que te ayudo hermano.

Comment: Hola @Pierro no pude hacerlo desde c# pero lo hice desde jquey añadiendo una asp:Button con la funcion OnClientClick="Print()" saludos